# What is the difference between these GUID's in wordpress feed?

Tags: rss, feed, guids

My RSS feed currently contains generated post GUIDs URLs that use the post slug:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">https://sitename.com/postname/</guid>
```

However I want to use the ?p=postID format instead:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">https://sitename.com/?p=3566</guid>
```

How can I change this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Shivani, welcome to WPSE. To improve the odds of getting an useful answer question, I would suggest you to [add a little bit more of context, and information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). And also explain what you already tried or strategies you might been thinking. Also, what your knowledge and skill with WordPress is.

Comment: That string is read from the guid column in wp_posts, so you could change it in there. However I can't immediately see how it's generated for new post records.

Comment: The `guid` is _not_ the link to the post. It's a unique identifier, and is used to make sure that duplicate posts aren't pulled into feeds. It's not user-facing, so there should be no reason to change it.

Comment: @Shivani Shukla I would also like to do this - I'm using a custom post type and it's showing the URL in the RSS feed for the GUID but I would like to add a unique identifier in there.  Did you manage to modify it ?